# Adding device to a distribution provisioning profile with which a app is already at app store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I am trying to port my apps from 6.1 to 7 so I made a couple of changes and checked them using a development provisioning profile. Now when I am trying to add device to a distribution provisioning profile in Member Center so that I can make archive, I am not able to see any option where as If I log in another account, I can see option to add device.

I am countered with:

> None of the valid provisioning profiles include the device My Phone’s iPhone (identifier: 0606ac18f7e3f55efc691ece3997db35aa273b2b).

I always do this by going to Member Center and then download the provisioning profile again to work it out however this time I am not able to see the option.

Comment: Can I just delete this provisioning profile and recreate it with same name and then update the app to App Store?

Comment: Yes you can. But you cant select devices for the provisional profile which is used to upload the application on the store.

Comment: I didn't get your point

Comment: You can not add the devices in the distribution profile which is used to upload the application on the store.

Comment: Will there be any problem to the already submitted app if I delete the provisioning profile and add new device to upload the update ?

Comment: Then how will can I make archive if I will not include the device in distribution provisioning ?